# libvlc / python how to make the VLC player instance "always on top"?

Tags: python, libvlc

I am using libvlc to control a vlc isntance from python and it works well.
The option I can not found though is "always on top". I can set it through the menu of the mini instance. But I d like to set it from the code. Any idea?
Thanks

## method to play video

```
import time, vlc

def video2(source):
    # creating vlc media player object
    media_player = vlc.MediaPlayer()
  
    # media object
    media = vlc.Media(source)

    # setting media to the media player
    media_player.set_media(media)

    # setting video scale
    media_player.video_set_scale(0.6)
    media_player.audio_set_mute(True)
    # setting play rate
    # doubles the speed of the video
    media_player.set_rate(1.5)
    # start playing video
    media_player.play()

    # wait so the video can be played for 5 seconds
    # irrespective for length of video
    time.sleep(5)
    return media_player
```

Comment: That's a UI/OS concern, not really a libvlc function

Comment: Are you sure? as you can can define the size of the window player by media_player.video_set_scale(0.6) I assumed it s the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using an external dependency, `PyWinCtl` can make the trick in most cases. Take a look to this (open a VLC instance before testing it and insert the title of the video you're playing in the script):

```
import pywinctl as pwc

windows = pwc.getWindowsWithTitle("title/of/your/video", pwc.Re.CONTAINS)
if windows:
    w = windows[0]
    # Use w.alwaysOnTop(False) to stop always-on-top behavior
    w.alwaysOnTop()
else:
    print("NOT FOUND! Check the video title)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. [The document called Module vlc](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/) doesn't show the option you are looking for.